# PHP: How to Group and Sum Up in Array

Tags: php

This is my array

```
array(
      ['studentId'=>"M100030","isbn"=>"0199535566",'price'=>"15.00"],
      ['studentId'=>"M100030","isbn"=>"0199535566",'price'=>"13.50"],
      ['studentId'=>"M100030","isbn"=>"0143105426",'price'=>"20.00"],
      ['studentId'=>"M100035","isbn"=>"1604501480",'price'=>"21.00"],
      ['studentId'=>"M100035","isbn"=>"1604501480",'price'=>"23.00"],
      ['studentId'=>"M100035","isbn"=>"0199535566",'price'=>"14.00"],
      ['studentId'=>"M103233","isbn"=>"0061964360",'price'=>"18.50"],
    );
```

I want to group the studentId and isbn then sum up the price to JSON

```
{
   "M100030":{
      "0199535566":{
         "amount":"28.50"
      },
      "0143105426":{
         "amount":"20.00"
      }
   },
   "M100035":{
      "1604501480":{
         "amount":"44.00"
      },
      "0199535566":{
         "amount":"14.00"
      }
   },
   "M103233":{
      "0061964360":{
         "amount":"18.50"
      }
   }
}
```

The method I tried so far to group the studentId and isbn, but not able to get the expected result. Anyone can correct my code?

```
foreach ($check['rentout'] as $key=> $values)
{

    $keys = $values['studentId'];
    if (!array_key_exists($keys,$trx)){
      $trx[$keys] = array('isbn'=>$values['isbn'],'amount'=>$values['price']);
    }else{
      $trx[$keys]['amount'] = $trx[$keys]['amount']+$values['price'];
    }

}
```

Comment: Since you're doing arithmetic with decimals, you should take a look at [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$students = array(
      ['studentId'=>"M100030","isbn"=>"0199535566",'price'=>"15.00"],
      ['studentId'=>"M100030","isbn"=>"0199535566",'price'=>"13.50"],
      ['studentId'=>"M100030","isbn"=>"0143105426",'price'=>"20.00"],
      ['studentId'=>"M100035","isbn"=>"1604501480",'price'=>"21.00"],
      ['studentId'=>"M100035","isbn"=>"1604501480",'price'=>"23.00"],
      ['studentId'=>"M100035","isbn"=>"0199535566",'price'=>"14.00"],
      ['studentId'=>"M103233","isbn"=>"0061964360",'price'=>"18.50"],
    );
```

I Created variable `$res` and I looped over *$students* and get the `$student_id` and do a test if there is no *isbn* for this student, If So set their `amount` to the initial value, and loop again if we find it again accumulate its *prices* to `amount`, and do this again and again to all students in the array.

```php
$res = [];
foreach ($students as $key => $student) {
    $student_id = $student['studentId'];
    if (!isset($res[$student_id][$student["isbn"]])){
      $res[$student_id][$student["isbn"]]["amount"] = $student['price'];
    }else{
        $res[$student_id][$student["isbn"]]["amount"] += $student['price'];
    }
}
```

```php
echo "<pre>";
echo json_encode($res, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**Print*(as excpected)*

```
{
    "M100030": {
        "0199535566": {
            "amount": 28.5
        },
        "0143105426": {
            "amount": "20.00"
        }
    },
    "M100035": {
        "1604501480": {
            "amount": 44
        },
        "0199535566": {
            "amount": "14.00"
        }
    },
    "M103233": {
        "0061964360": {
            "amount": "18.50"
        }
    }
}
```